# I have every info about line segment how do I calculate a point on it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        float DistanceToCenter = Vector2.Distance(NatPos, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));

        if (isLaunched == false)mechanic (bkz. line_15)
        {
            if(DistanceToCenter < LimitToDistance)
            {
                Vector3 newPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                transform.position = new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, 0);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

So this lets me move my character when it's not far from its spawn point, but it also causes my character to stop moving when my mouse is out of range.
I want it to head for my mouse within the limits.
[image: image to Explain it better]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this by first testing if the mouse is close enough (like you're already doing). If it is you set the position of the character to the position of the mouse. If it's not you set the position of the character to be the max distance away from the center in the direction of the mouse. It can be accomplished with this code:

```
Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
float distanceToCenter = Vector2.Distance(NatPos, mousePos);

if(distanceToCenter < LimitToDistance){
    transform.position = mousePos;
}
else{
    Vector2 directionFromCenter = (mousePos - NatPos).normalized;

    Vector2 newPosition = NatPos + directionFromCenter * LimitToDistance;
    transform.position = newPosition;
}
```

[image: Demonstration]

(Note that I've added a gizmo to show how far it can go)

---

I will try to explain in detail what this code does.

The first 2 lines are pretty self-explanatory as they simply get and store the mouse position and the distance from the mouse to the center.

The next few lines simply check if the mouse is within the circle and if it is it sets the position of the character to the mouse position.

The next line gets the direction of the mouse from the center by subtracting the center position from the mouse position. It then normalizes it, i.e. makes it exactly 1 unit long.

The next line gets the new position of the character by multiplying the direction vector we got earlier by the max distance. It also adds the position of the center to make sure it is... well, centered around the center.

The last line simply sets the position of the character to the position we got in the previous line.

Note that this code will only work if `NatPos` is a `Vector2`. If it's a `Vector3` you will get errors. To fix them, simply add `(Vector2)` in front of `NatPos` on the lines you get errors to convert it to a `Vector2`, i.e. `(Vector2)NatPos`.

---

Side note: You should not be using `Camera.main` repeatedly, because every time you use it, it runs an expensive bit of code. You should rather use it once and store the result in a variable that you use instead. E.g:

```
Camera mainCam; //Use this variable instead of Camera.main

void Start()
{
    mainCam = Camera.main;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was my first post in here ever. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because once `DistanceToCenter < LimitToDistance`  evaluates as false, no newPosition will be calculated.

But this seems a bit off.. You could try by using a circle collider and just make the player gameobject follow the mouse position.

Comment: if I put a circle collider it will just glitch, wdym exactly ?

Comment: use continuous collision detection